# I get "greedy.c:17:1: error: expected identifier or '(' {" Can someone help? It is referring to the line after int main(void)

Tags: c, identifier, cs50

```
/**************************************************
 * Greedy.c
 *
 * CS50x pset1
 * Daniel Riley
 *
 * A program that determines the minimum amount of
 * coins used for change owed
 *
 *
 **************************************************/
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <cs50.h>
 #include <math.h>

 int main (void);
 {

 float change;
 int cents = round (change * 100);
 int coins = 0;

 do
     {
     printf("How much change is required? ");
     change = GetFloat();
     }
 while(change < 0);

 do
     {
     cents -= 25;
     coins ++;
     }
 while(cents >= 25);

 do
     {
     cents -= 10;
     coins ++;
     }
 while(cents >= 10);

 do
     {
     cents -= 5;
     coins ++;
     }
 while(cents >= 5);

 do
     {
     cents -= 1;
     coins ++;
     }
 while(cents >= 1);

 printf("%d\n", coins);
 return 0;
 }
```

I Get an error expected identifier '(' when compiling please help. It is line 17 the line after int main(void). As far as I can tell I have bracketed all functions correctly. The program has to ask a user for change and determine the least number of coins to use in giving change

Comment: In passing, you are using the value of variable `change` while it is uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the line after `int main(void)`, it's the line after `int main (void);`. In other words, remove the `;` in line 16.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
}
```

Miss out the `;` in line 16

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon after `main()` function..